# Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncLock stack overflow with lots of awaiters and synchronous fast path

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, .net-4.5

I'm using `AsyncLock` from Stephen Cleary's `Nito.AsyncEx` NuGet package (v3.0.1) to protect the initialization of an expensive resource, so only the first caller will perform the time-consuming asynchronous initialization, and all subsequent callers will wait asynchronously until the initialization is done and then get the cached resource.

What I first noticed is that the code following the region protected by the `AsyncLock` was executing in the tasks in the **exact** reverse order the tasks were started in (i.e. the last task started got to continue past the locked region first, then the second to last task, and so on until the first task continued last).

Then in the process of investigating why that was happening I discovered I consistently get a stack overflow when there are a large number of the asynchronous tasks.  Here's a simplified example:

```
object _foo;
readonly Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncLock _fooLock = new Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncLock();

async Task<object> GetFooAsync()
{
    using (await _fooLock.LockAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        if (_foo == null)
        {
            // Simulate time-consuming asynchronous initialization,
            // during which all the subsequent tasks end up awaiting the AsyncLock.
            await Task.Delay(5000).ConfigureAwait(false);
            _foo = new object();
        }
        return _foo;
    }
}

async Task DoStuffAsync()
{
    object foo = await GetFooAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    // Do stuff with foo...
}

void DoStuff()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(DoStuffAsync());
    }

    Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait();
}
```

If the fast path through `GetFooAsync()` is not synchronous (e.g. if I add `await Task.Yield();` right before `return _foo;`) then not only does the stack overflow not occur, but the tasks continue past the locked region in the order they were started in.

I'll probably be changing my code to use `AsyncLazy<T>` from AsyncEx instead for this use case, which I've tested and does not seem to exhibit this problem.

However, I'd like to know if this problem is due to a mistake in my code, a bug in `AsyncLock`, or is it just expected behavior (more of a gotcha)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [bug in `AsyncLock`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/issues/36); all the queue-based asynchronous coordination primitives have the same problem. A fix is in the works.

The [new version of this library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx.Coordination) has a rewritten queue which does not suffer from this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!  Any idea when the fix might make it in?  Or anything that can be done to help with that?

I'd love to use the new version, but the system the code has to run on is currently stuck with .NET 4.5 and the new version seems to require .NET 4.6.

Comment: The delay is just due to the lack of a build machine that supports downlevel platforms (like WP7.1 and SL4). I've decided to move forward with a build only for newer problems, so this will be a `4.x` version. Hopefully this weekend at some point. The new version does require net46 - the new async queue requires it.